# Why is this `while` loop not iterating and just exiting?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, connect-four

```
function aiPick() {
    let aiCell = null;
    while (aiCell == null) {
      let aiColIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7)
      console.log(aiColIndex)
      aiCell = getFirstOpenCellForColumn(aiColIndex) 
      console.log(typeof(aiCell))
      console.log(getClassListArray(aiCell))
    }
    aiCell.classList.add('red')
    checkStatusOfGame(aiCell)
    yellowIsNext = !yellowIsNext
    aiClassList = getClassListArray(aiCell)
    aiColClass = aiClassList.find(className => className.includes('col'));
    let aiColIndex = parseInt(aiColClass[4], 10);
    clearColorFromTop(aiColIndex)
}
```

I'm working on an opponent for a Connect Four game. I'm having it pick one of seven columns by random, and then the function `getFirstOpenCellForColumn` will mark the first open cell by adding a class of `red` to that `div`.

The code then checks if the move is a win with `checkStatusOfGame(aiCell)` and swaps the player and removes a token that shows up at the top of the column, outside the gameboard, that serves as a "picker."

I was looking for a way to get the computer to generate a new random number to pick a column when the last space in the column was occupied. I thought this would do it, since when the computer picks a full column, it gives me this error message:

```
script.js:39 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
    at getClassListArray (script.js:39)
    at aiPick (script.js:274)
    at HTMLDivElement.handleCellClick (script.js:258)
```

But then it seems not to go back to picking a random number, but simply jumps down to `yellowIsNext = !yellowIsNext` so that I'm now placing the computer's red token instead of my yellow ones.

Basically, I want the code to

1. pick a random number
2. put the token in the column corresponding to that number
3. if that column is full, go back to #1

Do you know why this isn't working? Is there another way to write the `while` loop, or is `let aiCell = null` incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: your error is inside `getClassListArray`, which is still in the loop

Comment: The loop is fine. The problem is that you do `console.log(getClassListArray(aiCell))` even if `aiCell` is null.

Comment: That should be outside the loop, so you don't do it until you've found a cell.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for taking a look. Oh, I see, I shot myself in the foot there! I added `console.log(getClassListArray(aiCell))` just to see what was going on, but when that draws an error, it throws the whole loop. When I take it out, the loop works fine. Valuable lesson!

Comment: @ProGu, thanks as well, I see that's what you were saying too.